# Performance of MERGE vs. UPDATE with subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

Note that I've modified table/field names etc. for readability. Some of the original names are quite confusing.

I have three different tables:

```
Retailer (Id+Code is a unique key)
- Id
- Code
- LastReturnDate
- ...

Delivery/DeliveryHistory (combination of Date+RetailerId is unique)
- Date
- RetailerId
- HasReturns
- ...
```

`Delivery` and `DeliveryHistory` are almost identical. Data is periodically moved to the history table, and there's no surefire way to know when this last happened. In general, the Delivery-table is quite small -- usually less than 100,000 rows -- while the history table will typically have millions of rows.

My task is to update the `LastReturnDate` field for each retailer based on the current highest date value for which `HasReturns` is true in Delivery *or* DeliveryHistory.

Previously this has been solved with a view defined as follows:

```sql
SELECT Id, Code, MAX(Date) Date
   FROM Delivery
   WHERE HasReturns = 1
   GROUP BY Id, Code
UNION
SELECT Id, Code, MAX(Date) Date
   FROM DeliveryHistory
   WHERE HasReturns = 1
   GROUP BY Id, Code
```

And the following UPDATE statement:

```sql
UPDATE Retailer SET LastReturnDate = (
    SELECT MAX(Date) FROM DeliveryView
    WHERE Retailer.Id = DeliveryView.Id AND Retailer.Code = DeliveryView.Code)
WHERE Code = :Code AND EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM DeliveryView
    WHERE Retailer.Id = DeliveryView.Id AND Retailer.Code = DeliveryView.Code
    HAVING
        MAX(Date) > LastReturnDate OR
        (LastReturnDate IS NULL AND MAX(Date) IS NOT NULL))
```

The EXISTS-clause guards against updating fields where the current value is greater than the new one, but this is actually not a significant concern, because it's hard to see how that could ever happen during normal program execution. Note also how the `AND Max(Date) IS NOT NULL` part is in fact superfluous, since it's impossible for Date to be null in DeliveryView. But the EXISTS-clause appears to actually improve performance slightly.

However, the performance of the UPDATE has recently been horrendous. In a database where the Retailer table contains only 1000-2000 relevant entries, the UPDATE has been taking more than five minutes to run. Note that it does this even if I remove the entire EXISTS clause, i.e. with this very simply statement:

```sql
UPDATE Retailer SET LastReturnDate = (
    SELECT MAX(Date) FROM DeliveryView
    WHERE Retailer.Id = DeliveryView.Id AND Retailer.Code = DeliveryView.Code)
WHERE Code = :Code
```

I've therefore been looking into a better solution. My first idea was to create a temporary table, but after a while I tried to write it as a MERGE statement:

```sql
MERGE INTO Retailer
USING (SELECT Id, Code, MAX(Date) Date FROM DeliveryView GROUP BY Id, Code)
    ON (Retailer.Id = DeliveryView.Id AND Retailer.Code = DeliveryView.Code)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET LastReturnDate = Date WHERE Code = :Code
```

This seems to work, and it's more than an order of magnitude faster than the UPDATE.

**I have three questions**:

1. Can I be certain that this will have the same effect as the UPDATE in all cases (disregarding the edge case of LastReturnDate already being larger than MAX(Date))?
2. Why is it so much faster?
3. Is there some better solution?

## Query plans

### MERGE plan

Cost: 25,831, Bytes: 1,143,828

#### Plain language

1. Every row in the table SCHEMA.Delivery is read.
2. The rows were sorted in order to be grouped.
3. Every row in the table SCHEMA.DeliveryHistory is read.
4. The rows were sorted in order to be grouped.
5. Return all rows from steps 2, 4 - including duplicate rows.
6. The rows from step 5 were sorted to eliminate duplicate rows.
7. A view definition was processed, either from a stored view SCHEMA.DeliveryView or as defined by steps 6.
8. The rows were sorted in order to be grouped.
9. A view definition was processed, either from a stored view SCHEMA. or as defined by steps 8.
10. Every row in the table SCHEMA.Retailer is read.
11. The result sets from steps 9, 10 were joined (hash).
12. A view definition was processed, either from a stored view SCHEMA.  or as defined by steps 11.
13. Rows were merged.
14. Rows were remotely merged.

#### Technical

```
Plan                                            Cardinality Distribution
14 MERGE STATEMENT REMOTE  ALL_ROWS
Cost: 25 831  Bytes: 1 143 828                                              3 738   
    13 MERGE SCHEMA.Retailer ORCL                                           
        12 VIEW SCHEMA.                                         
            11 HASH JOIN  
            Cost: 25 831  Bytes: 1 192 422                                  3 738   
                9 VIEW SCHEMA. 
                Cost: 25 803  Bytes: 194 350                            7 475   
                    8 SORT GROUP BY  
                    Cost: 25 803  Bytes: 194 350                        7 475   
                        7 VIEW VIEW SCHEMA.DeliveryView ORCL
                        Cost: 25 802  Bytes: 194 350                    7 475   
                            6 SORT UNIQUE  
                            Cost: 25 802  Bytes: 134 550                7 475   
                                5 UNION-ALL                 
                                    2 SORT GROUP BY  
                                    Cost: 97  Bytes: 25 362         1 409   
                                        1 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE SCHEMA.Delivery [Analyzed] ORCL
                                        Cost: 94  Bytes: 210 654    11 703  
                                    4 SORT GROUP BY  
                                    Cost: 25 705  Bytes: 109 188        6 066   
                                        3 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE SCHEMA.DeliveryHistory [Analyzed] ORCL
                                        Cost: 16 827  Bytes: 39 333 636     2 185 202   
                10 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE SCHEMA.Retailer [Analyzed] ORCL
                Cost: 27  Bytes: 653 390                            2 230
```

### UPDATE plan

Cost: 101,492, Bytes: 272,060

#### Plain language

1. Every row in the table SCHEMA.Retailer  is read.
2. One or more rows were retrieved using index SCHEMA.DeliveryHasReturns . The index was scanned in ascending order.
3. Rows from table SCHEMA.Delivery  were accessed using rowid got from an index.
4. The rows were sorted in order to be grouped.
5. One or more rows were retrieved using index SCHEMA.DeliveryHistoryHasReturns . The index was scanned in ascending order.
6. Rows from table SCHEMA.DeliveryHistory  were accessed using rowid got from an index.
7. The rows were sorted in order to be grouped.
8. Return all rows from steps 4, 7 - including duplicate rows.
9. The rows from step 8 were sorted to eliminate duplicate rows.
10. A view definition was processed, either from a stored view SCHEMA.DeliveryView  or as defined by steps 9.
11. The rows were sorted in order to be grouped.
12. A view definition was processed, either from a stored view SCHEMA.  or as defined by steps 11.
13. Rows were updated.
14. Rows were remotely updated.

#### Technical

```
Plan                                        Cardinality Distribution
14 UPDATE STATEMENT REMOTE  ALL_ROWS
Cost: 101 492  Bytes: 272 060                                       1 115   
    13 UPDATE SCHEMA.Retailer ORCL                                      
        1 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE SCHEMA.Retailer [Analyzed] ORCL
        Cost: 27  Bytes: 272 060                                1 115   
        12 VIEW SCHEMA. 
        Cost: 90  Bytes: 52                                 2   
            11 SORT GROUP BY  
            Cost: 90  Bytes: 52                             2   
                10 VIEW VIEW SCHEMA.DeliveryView ORCL
                Cost: 90  Bytes: 52                         2   
                    9 SORT UNIQUE  
                    Cost: 90  Bytes: 36                     2   
                        8 UNION-ALL                     
                            4 SORT GROUP BY  
                            Cost: 15  Bytes: 18             1   
                                3 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE SCHEMA.Delivery [Analyzed] ORCL
                                Cost: 14  Bytes: 108        6   
                                    2 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX SCHEMA.DeliveryHasReturns [Analyzed] ORCL
                                    Cost: 2     12  
                            7 SORT GROUP BY  
                            Cost: 75  Bytes: 18             1   
                                6 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE SCHEMA.DeliveryHistory [Analyzed] ORCL
                                Cost: 74  Bytes: 4 590          255 
                                    5 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX SCHEMA.DeliveryHistoryHasReturns [Analyzed] ORCL
                                    Cost: 6     509
```

Comment: Not sure why you've shown your interpretation of the plans rather than the actual plans - just because the names are different? Does 'remotely merged/updated' imply there's a database link involved? If so I guess that's in the `deliveryView`, and you're accessing that link for each subselect (i.e. once per row that matches `:code`)?

Comment: @AlexPoole Those lists are actually a "plain language" description of the plan generated by Toad for Data Analysts. I figured they would be easier to interpret, but I can paste it in a different format if that's better. I'm not sure what the meaning of "remotely updated/merged" is. There's no database link involved as far as I know.

Comment: I use merge as well when heavy updates required, and it is faster. I usually join on rowid though. Not sure if it's better or not, but asking if you can certian, it totally depends on you.

Comment: @MagnusGrindalBakken You may want to try `explain plan for <your query>;` and then `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display));`  It will generate a nicer-looking and more common text format.